# Functional Minimization of Exponential Decay

Tags: optimization, euler-lagrange-equation

I would like to find a function $f$ that minimizes the functional:

$$\ln(f(x))f(x)-\frac1x$$

over some range of $x > 0$.

Is this a good application for functional calculus and the Euler-Lagrange differential equation?
If not, does anyone have any other method for finding a minimizing function?